# What's the best way to do a psql export that does a regex replace across all columns?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm running PSQL exports to CSV files for a few tables. They look like the below:

```
COPY table_name TO 'file_name' CSV
```

The issue is that some of these tables have `text` fields, in which the values for these fields contain both the delimiter (commas) and newlines. What would be the best way to do the export while removing the newlines across all columns?

Example table:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
field1,field2,"field3, with, the delimiter",field4
field1,field2,"field3, with, the
delimiter and newline",field4
field1,"field2 with a
newline",field3,field4
```

How I'd want my export to look:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
field1,field2,"field3, with, the delimiter",field4
field1,field2,"field3, with, the delimiter and newline",field4
field1,"field2 with a newline",field3,field4
```

Some solutions I've been considering:

1. Write a custom regex replace function and update the tables before I do the export.
2. See if there is a way to do the replace during the export transaction (is this possible?).
3. Perform the export as is and use another library/language to post-process the exported CSV.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another way: create a view that implements the data transformation and export the view.  But what does "best" mean here?  What problem are the embedded newlines causing to the consumer of these CSV files?  Have you tried any of the alternatives and found specific issues with them that you need help with?

Comment: Thanks for response @rd_nielsen. The data parser being used downstream on these CSV files can't handle embedded newlines (specifically parser cannot be serialized to run on the compute engine in use). An acceptable solution is to convert replace these embedded newlines.

If there is a query used to generate the view, can't I use the same query to export my data in that format?

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically compose an appropriate `COPY` statement with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT format(
          'COPY (SELECT %s FROM %I.%I) TO ''filename'' (FORMAT ''csv'');',
          string_agg(
             format(
                CASE WHEN data_type IN ('text', 'character varying', 'character')
                     THEN 'translate(%I, E''\n,'', '''')'
                     ELSE '%I'
                END,
                column_name
             ),
             ', '
             ORDER BY ordinal_position
          ),
          table_schema,
          table_name
       )
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
  AND table_name = 'table_name'
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name;
```

If you are using `psql`, you can replace the final semicolon with `\gexec` to have `psql` run the resulting SQL statement for you in one go.